# What does it mean by consistency of MLE in case of regression

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood

I was going through Linear regression slides of a university and on slides 18 , 19 I cannot understand what is the difference between W* and W(mle) or W(ols) .
We find W* by minimizing e which is found by MLE or OLS method and both give the same solution . What is the quantity on the Y axis of the graph ?
[Please refer to slide 18 , 19](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/bhaskarm/LinReg.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf{w}^*$ is the *true* vector of coefficients of the underlying model. $\mathbf{w}_{OLS}$ and $\mathbf{w}_{MLE}$ are the same and estimates of $\mathbf{w}^*$ using the data, where the former is obtained via minimization of MSE, the latter is obtained via minimization of negative log-likelihood. The plot symbolizes the convergence of OLS/MLE solutions to the true parameter as number of data points increases, which is an indicator of *consistency*.

Comment: What do you mean by true parameter . Is W* a parameter which minimizes e ? I am confused , we do not know w* beforehand , if we would know there is no need of regression model .

Comment: consider that your data is generated with $w^*x+e$, (e.g. you're simulating your data), and then try to figure out what $w$ is from the data as if you don't know anything. Your estimate (i.e. OLS, MLE etc.) will be different than the true parameter set, $w^*$ because it's just what your data tells you.